# Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\temp1\list.pdf" could not be opened. Operating system error code 997

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I am using an SQL Server that is connected with

- Service Type: Database Engine
- Server name: `cloudquotedev.database.windows.net`
- Authentication: SQL Server Auth with given User name and Password

When I run following SQL statement I am getting an error:

```
insert into attachments 
values (1, 'Holiday List 2022', 'PDF',
        (select * 
         from Openrowset(BULK 'C:\temp1\export_holiday_list.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) as pdf))
```

Error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\temp1\export_holiday_list.pdf" could not be opened. Operating system error code 997 (Overlapped I/O operation is in progress).

Comment: Remember, paths are relative to the *server* not to your PC.